# How can I get this C program to call this function without modifying the code?

Tags: c, function, call

I was wondering if it was possible to get ret to be called without modifying the code.  Thanks for looking!

```
    #undef _FORTIFY_SOURCE
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <unistd.h>

    int ret() {
        return system("/bin/bash");
    }

    void overflow() {
        char buf[128];
        read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, 256);
    }

    void user() {
        gid_t gid = getegid();
        setresgid(gid, gid, gid);
    }

    int main(int argc, char** argv) {
            user();
            overflow();
    }
```

Comment: Don't specify pointless restrictions without giving us a *good* reason. Is this some homework question? If so, say so.

Comment: Does that include main?

Comment: Yeah, I cannot modify any of the code.

Comment: Your professor is giving you a big hint in the naming of the function `overflow`.

Comment: I think I got it to overflow by spamming characters until I got a Segmentation Fault, but I don't know where to go from there. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, still lost though.

Answer (score 0):

What your teacher wants you to do here is a buffer overflow.

The program will read from STDIN, so pipe in more than 256 chars and I think you will be on the way to finishing your assignment.

Comment: I tried that originally. I just got a Segmentation Fault, ret() was never called.

Comment: Take a look at the dump (the stack in particular) and you'll find out what you have to write to stdin to not segfault.

Comment: Not sure how to examine the stack or dump after it crashing. Any insight?

Comment: You'll want to use a debugger for that. If you're running Linux or similar, you can use GDB.

Comment: Here is some good reading on the subject of overflows: http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html

Comment: @user2348650 There are  [a ton of articles](http://bit.ly/15cVZNC) if you just look for them.